# Is it safe to use OpenSSL?

Tags: asp.net-core, openssl

I'm trying to use OpenSSL,
but I'm worried about the legality, saying its illegal in some parts of the world.
I'm going to use it while on development with my net core app that 's using Autodesk Forge API.

Comment: "Saying its illegal in some parts of the world" where? If it's illegal in *your* part of the world, don't use it. Otherwise, do. This is really a legal question.